# How to assign comment to the post commented on

Tags: python, django

I'm Django beginner. I am trying to implement a code on how to implement a comment form in home page and also display its comments.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    imageuploader_profile=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) 
    upload_image=models.ImageField() 

class Comments(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    commented_image=models.ForeignKey(Image,....)
    comment_post=models.TextField()

def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=CommentForm(request. POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment=form.save(commit=False)
            comment.user=request.user
            comment.commented_image=post
            comment.save()
            return redirect.... 
    else:
        form=CommentForm
```

HOME template

```
{% for comment  in all_images %}
{{ comment.comment_post }}
{% endfor %}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Am I correct that you want to be able to make html form in template so user can pass a comment? or you want already made comment visible to everyone?

Comment: @Hisham... How do I query comment for each post, my comment form works and all comments are saved in database. But how do I show this comment in home template?

Comment: @Hisham... When I use this: img=Image objects.filter(imageuploader_profile=request.user) comments=Comments object.filter(commemted_image__in=img). This shows all comment on template but not assign each comment in post commented on. How do I get all comment to display on each post I commented on?

Comment: do you have this code on github or anywhere it will be much easier to solve this problem.

Comment: @Hisham... No I don't. I can attached the images of my views and template here. Will that be okay for you?

Comment: yes, it will be okay.

Comment: @Hisham... I have updated my question. Please check it and let me know if you want any other image attached to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed context in your second image, see if this solves the problem.

```
context = {'all_images': all_images, 'comments': comments}
```

Edited:

Edit `home.html`

```
{% for image in all_images %}
 <img src="{{ image.upload_image"}} />

 {% for comment in comments %}
   {% if comment.commented_image == image %}  
     {{ comment.comment_post }}
   {% else %}
     No comments available.
   {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Edited (2):
For count of comments without active do:

Edit `views.py`

```
# change
all_images = Image.objects.filter(imageuploader_profile=request.user)
...

for image in all_images:
    images_comment_count = []
    images_comment_count.append(Comments.objects.filter(commented_image_id=image.id, active=True).count())
...

context = {..., 'images_comment_count': images_comment_count}
```

Now, edit `home.html`

```
{% load index %}
...
{% for image in all_images %}
 <img src="{{ image.upload_image"}} />

 {% for comment in comments %}
   {% if comment.commented_image == image %}  
     {{ comment.comment_post }}
   {% else %}
     No comments available.
   {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}

  <!-- Comment Count CHANGED THIS -->
  {{ images_comment_count|index:forloop.counter0 }}
{% endfor %}
```

Edit 3:

yeah it shows it because we will now be creating custom tag filter.
1) create templatetags/ directory in the same apps folder
2) create a file called `__init__.py`
3) create another file called `index.py` we will be filling this file
4) Add the given code in `index.py`

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def index(indexable, i):
    return indexable[i]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210476/discussion-on-answer-by-hisham-pak-how-to-assign-comment-to-the-post-commented).