# How do I get the ID of an image

Tags: python, django

I'm a Django beginner, how do I get the ID of each image uploaded with form?

```
class Image(models.Model):
    imageuploader_profile=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    upload_image=models.ImageField() 

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post=form.save(commit=False)
            post.imageuploader_profile=request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect.... 
    else:
        form=UploadForm
    return render......
```

view.py

```
def home(request) :
    all_images=Image objects.filter(imageuploader_profile=request.user) 
    context={'all_images':all_images} 
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

My home.html

```
{% for post in all_images %}
{% if post upload_images %}
<img src="{{ post upload_image.url }}"> 
{% endif %}
{% endfor%}
```

I want to get all IDs in my template.

Comment: So you want something like `Image.objects.filter(uploaded_via='form')`? Then you need to store the information who the image got saved/created. If you just want to get all Images (because you only save them by form) then you can do `images = Image.objects.all()`.

Comment: @zypro... Can you update your answer with the form in my question. I seems confused on how I can get the ID of each image i uploaded with form. Where do you get 'uploaded_via' from?

Comment: The question rather is, where do you need all images? What do you want to do with this queryset? Then I can update your code. Or do you only need the current uploaded image ID?

Comment: @zypro... I want to upload an image that will be displayed in homepage, I was able to do that. But what I want now is to get the ID of each image i upload using form.

Comment: You are still unclear, please tell exactly what required output you want, for e.g. (I want list of every image id that users have uploaded in my template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a new method/view to get all IDs:

```
def get_images_ids():
    images_ids = Image.objects.values_list('id)
    print(images_ids)
    return images_ids
```

[Here the explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37205793/django-values-list-vs-values) for `values_list` (you also can use `values()` if you need more, or the attribute `flat=True`).

If you call `get_images_ids()` you get all IDs of all images in a queryset (or in a list with `flat=True`). If you need to filter them use `.filter()`.

In your views.py

```
def home(request) :
    all_images=Image objects.filter(imageuploader_profile=request.user) 
    context={'all_images':all_images, all_images_ids: get_images_ids()} 
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

In your template do this:

```
{% for post in all_images %}
    {% if post upload_images %}
        <img src="{{ post.upload_image.url }}">
        <span>{{ post.id }}</span>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor%}
```

or

```
<ul>
{% for id in all_images_ids %}
    <li>{{ id }}</li>
{% endfor%}
</ul>
```

Comment: How do I print out the ID, so I can see in console? And also I do I pass this in template. I will update my question so that it can be clear to you.

Comment: call `get_images_ids()` and print its output. `print(get_images_ids())`. To pass it into the template you can define it as an template tag, or add it the the desired view as an context value.

Comment: Any how and where do you want to print the id?

Comment: I want to print out the ID in console, so I can see myself when the image is uploaded. And how do I pass get_images_ids in template? Edit my template code in my question so I can understand.

Comment: @GistDomBlog Just asking, what is the purpose of passing `get_images_ids()` into template? `post.id approach is much better you will not be required even to create that function.

Comment: @zypro.. Thanks, I have just one one question to ask concerning how I can implement comment to each image i uploaded. I will update my question with comment model.

Comment: @zypro...i can not edit my question anymore. Click on this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60881660/how-to-create-comment-form

Comment: @zypro... Please kindly take a look at the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get id of the image unless you first create an object in database, in other words you will have to execute `post.save()` first and then you can run `post.id` to get id. Here is an example with your code.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    imageuploader_profile=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    upload_image=models.ImageField() 

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post=form.save(commit=False)
            post.imageuploader_profile=request.user
            post.save()
            print(post.id)  # This will print id of submitted post in your console 

            return redirect.... 
    else:
        form=UploadForm
```

Note: ID of post is automatically created in the database after you run `post.save()`

Comment: @Hisham...you are right but this is not what I exactly wanted. Thanks for your knowledge

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID of the image after `post.save()` executes.

So before the return statement you can access `post.id` or `post.pk` to get the image ID.

UPDATE:

```py
class Image(models.Model):
    imageuploader_profile=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    upload_image=models.ImageField() 

def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form=UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post=form.save(commit=False)
            post.imageuploader_profile=request.user
            post.save()

            # here you can access post.id or post.pk

            return redirect.... 
    else:
        form=UploadForm
```

If you want to get all uploaded images id then use `Image.objects.values_list('id)`

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how I can add your code to the form, can you please update your code with my form?